# way to find deley in ssh from each machine in group to each machine

Tags: linux, bash, ssh

we have 352 machine in our hadoop cluster

I want to capture the time of delay when we do ssh from any machine to any machine

for example on first machine as master1 we can do something like that

```
all_ips=/tmp/ip.txt

for i in ` awk '{print $1}' $all_ips ` do ssh $i pwd ; done
```

but still I how to capture the time that I execute the ssh until I get the output from ssh?

second

since I want to do the ssh from each machine to each machine , I will appreciate to get idea

Comment: Is there anything this is got to do with [python] tag?

Comment: Add time to the ssh command and so time ssh $i pwd

Comment: Capturing the elapsed time would be quite easy, e.g. in seconds you could `... do s=$(date +%s);  [ssh commands]; e=$(date +%s); let "t = $e - $s"; echo $t; done` But why do you need this delay in the first place?

Comment: maybe something like `parallel-ssh` helps ?